# How to define location of object files to GCC?

Tags: android, gcc

Android NDK has some additional object files like crtbegin_static.o

How to define location for that object files to the GCC during compilation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before but the answers don't show the steps in detail. Basically you need to convert the .o file to a static library and then link it in your build script.

Convert the .o file using a terminal command like this:

```
ar rcs somefile.a somefile.o somefile2.o somefile3.o
```

Then in your Android.mk, add this section at the top of the file (after the LOCAL_PATH := ... line):

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := somelib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := somefile.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Then at the bottom where you are building your main module:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := somelib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to define --sysroot="...", like this:

```
LDFLAGS="-Lc:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib \
--sysroot=c:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm"
```